# What is the syntax for a section of the binding access operator?

Tags: sections, livescript

I want to create a function that takes an object and returns a bound method, like this:

```
f = (~ m)
f(x)() # same as x.m()
```

However, this parses `~` as the unary bitwise NOT operator, rather than the binding access operator. IOW it compiles to `~change`. I want it to compile to `function(it) { return bind$(it, 'change'); }` instead.

Can I use a section for this (and what is the syntax) or do I have to write a lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be explicit about the fact it's a `DOT` operator.
This is currently not possible, but [I added it in for 1.3](https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/commit/6457566db6617d93d28589b85ce347222fe0d5d0).